# How to add Authenticator to dropwizard application

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard 0.7.0. The dropwizard documentation at https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/auth.html#basic-authentication tells me to add an authenticator in this way:

```
@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration, Environment environment) {
    environment.addProvider(
        new BasicAuthProvider<User>(
            new ExampleAuthenticator(), "SUPER SECRET STUFF"));
}
```

I expect that to be in my Application#run, but when I try the below, there is no method addProvider on my environment:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<ExampleConfiguration> {
    @Override
    public void run(ExampleConfiguration config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        UserController userController = injector.getInstance(UserController.class);
        environment.addProvider(new BasicAuthProvider<User>(new BasicAuthAuthenticator(userController), "aksdkaksdwj012934"));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I personally use:
environment.addResource(new BasicAuthProvider<>(
    new authenticate(auths), "SECRET SHHH"));
If that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Dropwizard 0.7.0 try:

```java
environment.jersey().register(new BasicAuthProvider<Subject>(new BasicAuthenticator(), "MyAuth"));
```